# Force F is given in terms of time t and distance x by F= A \sin Ct + B \cos Dx. Then dimensions of A/B and C/D are?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis

I tried this problem for while day but  i don't get it . I want the method of solving it

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I downvote for lack of effort.  It is also quite clear from the comment to the answer that the OP only wants a solution and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments to trig functions (like exponentials) must be dimensionless. That is to say, the units should cancel on the inside. Thus, C and t must have the inverse units of each other. Similarly, D and x must have inverse units of each other. Now, we have F on the left hand side, so we must have each term on the right hand side with the same units. Thus because trig functions are unitless, the units of A and B must be the same as the units of F.